# New top bar quick reference guide / Where has the link to <X> gone?

Tags: support

Over the last 24 hours - since the new top bar has been rolled out - a number of different people, established and new users alike have asked questions on where a specific link has disappeared to with the new top bar design. Where has the link to `<X>` gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quick reference hit list on where to find links to various functions:

### Link to chat

Chat used to have a link on the top bar, next to your user statistics preview.

The new chat link is available by clicking on the "Stack Exchange" logo for the site whose chat rooms you want to access and clicking on "Chat" next to the site you're currently on. You still need to browse to individual sites to be taken directly to that site's chat page, but accessing any sites' chat page will still allow you to find chats from different sites if you wish to access them this way.

[image]

### Privileges overview

The list of available privileges including a breakdown of how much reputation you need to get to the next privilege used to be available by opening up your user statistics preview and clicking on privileges.

The same privilege view is still available, albeit it's now within the help center. To access this page, click on "help" to open the help menu and go to "Help Center". From here, under "Privileges", select "View a full list of privileges you can earn".

### How can I get to a site's meta?

The meta site for an individual Stack Exchange site used to be available directly from the top bar.

Meta is now on the Stack Exchange menu, like chat. Simply click on the "Stack Exchange" logo for the site whose meta you want to access and click on "Meta" to get to the meta site.

Additionally, as a second method of getting to a site's meta, you can access meta from the "help" menu on the main site, by selecting "help" to open the help menu and then clicking on "Meta" to get to meta.

### What happened to the "about" link?

The about link used to link off to the "Tour" page and used to be available from the old top bar, next to "meta" and "chat".

The Tour page is now available by clicking on "help" to open the help menu followed by clicking on "Tour" to access the tour to Stack Exchange page.

### How can I see my activity now?

Formally, clicking on the little down arrow next to your user statistics preview on the top bar would open up a breakdown of how much reputation I've earned, any recent badges, and statistics on my recent voting habits. How can I see my activity now?

A breakdown of important activity related information is now available from the "Achievements" menu. This is available by clicking on [image], which will open up the Achievements menu:

[image]

This will give you a breakdown of all reputation and badges earned recently across the entire Stack Exchange network of sites.

The more verbose "activity" link that used to be on the old drop down linked to your profile, to access the full list of your activity on a site, go to your profile and click on the "Activity" tab.

Comment: That's the kalina I know! Always cooking meth.

Comment: I think you can also get to your privileges by clicking on the reputation number on your profile page

Comment: that just takes you to the reputation graph/detail breakdown page